# Coordinates in Github repository URL

Tags: qgis, leaflet, mapbox, repository, github

https://underjollyroger.github.io/EarlyIllinoisLandcover/#9/41.5774/-88.0609

Why are there coordinates showing up in the url of this repository? And is there a way to get rid of them? The repository is a leaflet map that was exported via the qgis2web plugin in QGIS. I'm using a Mapbox API key for the geocoder and the map tiles.

Answer (score 2):

The hash URL updates when you pan and zoom the map, and allows you to share a particular view of the map, for example:
https://underjollyroger.github.io/EarlyIllinoisLandcover/#12/41.5293/-87.8465

You can read more about [Leaflet Hash](https://github.com/mlevans/leaflet-hash)

If you don't want to include this, comment out or delete [line 69](https://github.com/UnderJollyRoger/EarlyIllinoisLandcover/blob/main/index.html#L69) and [line 116](https://github.com/UnderJollyRoger/EarlyIllinoisLandcover/blob/main/index.html#L116) from `index.html` in your repository

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the meantime, removing those two lines didn't change the URL.